# Is it possible to reference the javascript and css files in another assembly with MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC Extension dll that I want to add to all of my projects. It contains attributes and some custom tags that I created using the MVC engine and Twitter Bootstrap. Basically I want to store the js and css versions required for my extension class in the dll that I add to the main web project.

Is it possible to reference these in the Styles.Render / Scripts.Render methods or using script or link tags?

```
<link href="@Url.Content("somehowAccessADifferentDllHere")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<script src="@Url.Content("somehowAccessADifferentDllHere")"></script>
```

Comment: How are the JS/CSS scripts stored in the assembly? Embedded Resource?

Comment: I am researching what the main differences in using embedded and linked resources are. I am open to whatever is the best practice for something of this nature.

Comment: You could store the CSS or JS as a resource and write that directly inside a `<script>` element as plain Javascript using a an extension method to the HtmlHelper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wanted to do this very same thing when I started using MVC, I found it was a lot more difficult than perhaps it should be. It would seem that reflection is currently the only way to achieve this, the approach below relies on an internal method which is part of the .NET framework.

After some research this is the extension to `HtmlHelper` I ended up with.

```
    // Cached delegate
    private static Func<Assembly, string, bool, bool, ScriptManager, string> GetWebResourceUrlInternal = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a Url to a WebResource as a string
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="type">Any type in the same assembly as the Resource</param>
    /// <param name="resourcePath">The full resource Id in the specified assembly</param>
    public static string GetWebResourceUrl(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, Type type, string resourcePath) {

        // find the internal method in AssemblyResourceLoader and cache the reflected result
        if (GetWebResourceUrlInternal == null) {
            MethodInfo mi = typeof(System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader).GetMethod(
                    "GetWebResourceUrlInternal", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

            GetWebResourceUrlInternal = (Func<Assembly, string, bool, bool, ScriptManager, string>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(
                typeof(Func<Assembly, string, bool, bool, ScriptManager, string>), mi, true);
        }

        return GetWebResourceUrlInternal(Assembly.GetAssembly(type), resourcePath, false, false, null);
    }
```

To use this in your view

```
<link href="@Html.GetWebResourceUrl(typeof(YourLibClass), "styles.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

To make this slightly more 'friendly' I also overload `GetWebResourceUrl` so that it simply accepts a `resourcePath` parameter and uses a known `Type` which simplifies the usage to;

```
<link href="@Html.GetWebResourceUrl("styles.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: This is brilliant and exactly what I was thinking I was going to have to do.

Answer (score -1):

No you can't.

You can add a pre build command that copies the css and js to the main project but not referencing them from the external assembly.

No ASP.NET magic here.

Checkout [Build a composite mvc3 application](http://blog.longle.net/2012/03/29/building-a-composite-mvc3-application-with-pluggable-areas/) for more information.

Comment: So the best practice is still to create a nuget package that installs them as dependencies directly to the application and the reference them in the _layout page?

Comment: Well I have thought about that and it's seems as a good idea but a) you might not want to share your code with others and b) any new implementation at the working project doesn't propagate to the library

Comment: a) The package would be stored locally on the local Nuget repository I created for our build server (no internet access). b) I am going to use nugetter to create the package so everytime I update the library it will version the updated code

Comment: The local Nuget sounds a good solution and I hope it will work for you.